# Appending paragraphs according to the Similarity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I've two text files which have similar content but consists of different number of paragraphs. A text may contain different number of paragraphs. I want to append the paragraphs into a dataframe according to the similarity of it. Here are the conditions of it:

1. Both the text will append the first two paragraphs as its is in current paragraphs column for initializing.
2. It will be keeping record of the previous and the next paragraphs.
3. If **TextDoc1** has a same sentence as of a paragraph as **TextDoc2** append both in the same row of the respective current columns.
4. If **TextDoc1** has a sentence of a paragraph which is not in **TextDoc2**, then append the paragraph of **TextDoc1** as it is in its column and append a NULL value in **TextDoc2**  current paragraph column.
5. If **TextDoc2** has a sentence of a paragraph which is not in **TextDoc1**, then append the paragraph of **TextDoc2** as it is in its column and append a NULL value in **TextDoc1** column.

E.g.

**TEXT DOC 1**

Risk Factors

When any one or more of the following risks materialize from time to time, our business, reputation, financial condition, cash flows, and results of operations can be materially and adversely affected, and the trading price of our common stock could decline. These risk factors do not identify all risks that we face; our operations can also be affected by factors that are not presently known to us or that we currently consider to be immaterial to our operations. Due to risks and uncertainties, known and unknown, our past financial results may not be a reliable indicator of future performance, and historical trends should not be used to anticipate results or trends in future periods. Refer also to the other information set forth in this Form 10-K, including in the MD&A and Financial Statements and Supplemental Details sections.

Changes in our effective tax rate may reduce our net income.

A number of factors can increase our effective tax rate, which could reduce our net income, including changes in the volume and mix of profits earned and location of assets across jurisdictions with varying tax rates; the resolution of issues arising from tax audits, including payment of interest and penalties; changes in the valuation of our deferred tax assets and liabilities, and in deferred tax valuation allowances; adjustments to income taxes upon finalization of tax returns; increases in expenses not deductible for tax purposes, including impairments of goodwill; changes in available tax credits; changes in our ability to secure new, or renew existing, tax holidays and incentives; changes in US federal, state, or foreign tax laws or their interpretation, including changes in the US to the taxation of manufacturing enterprises and of non-US income and expenses and changes resulting from the adoption by countries of OECD recommendations or other legislative actions; changes in accounting standards; and our decision to repatriate non-US earnings for which we have not previously provided for local country withholding taxes incurred upon repatriation.

We have fluctuations in the amount and frequency of our stock repurchases.

We are not obligated to make repurchases under our stock repurchase program. The amount, timing, and execution of our repurchases fluctuate based on factors that include prioritizing cash for other purposes, such as investing in our business, including operational spending, capital spending, and acquisitions, and returning cash to our stockholders as dividend payments. Our stock repurchase program may be suspended or terminated at any time. Moreover, we cannot guarantee that repurchases will enhance long-term stockholder value. We expect our future stock repurchases to be significantly below our levels from the last few years.

**TEXT DOC 2**

Risk Factors

The following summarizes the material factors that make an investment in our securities speculative or risky. When any one or more of the following risks materialize from time to time, our business, reputation, financial condition, cash flows, and results of operations can be materially and adversely affected, and the trading price of our common stock could decline. These risk factors do not identify all risks that we face; our operations can also be affected by factors that are not presently known to us or that we currently consider to be immaterial to our operations. Due to risks and uncertainties, known and unknown, our past financial results may not be a reliable indicator of future performance, and historical trends should not be used to anticipate results or trends in future periods. Refer also to the other information set forth in this Form 10-K, including in the MD&A and Financial Statements and Supplemental Details sections.

We have fluctuations in our stock price and the amount and frequency of our stock repurchases.

Our stock price can experience periods of significant volatility. For example, in 2022, our stock price ranged from a closing high of $55.91 to a closing low of $25.04. Changes in stock price or volume can also occur for the semiconductor industry more broadly, and may occur without regard to underlying company performance. Changes in our stock price can be driven by a variety of factors within or outside of our control, including the risks described above in these risk factors, as well as: fluctuations in national and global markets; fluctuations in our operating results and projections; announcements by us or our competitors; sentiment, speculation, valuation, analyses, or recommendations of stock analysts, social media, and the press; our credit rating; changes in holders of our stock; significant litigation or regulatory actions; and other periodic events.

We are not obligated to make repurchases under our stock repurchase program. The amount, timing, and execution of any share repurchases fluctuate based on factors that include prioritizing cash for other purposes, such as investing in our business, including operational spending, capital spending, and acquisitions, returning cash to our stockholders as dividend payments, and any regulatory restrictions. Our stock repurchase program may be suspended or terminated at any time. Moreover, we cannot guarantee that repurchases will enhance long-term stockholder value. We expect our future stock repurchases to be significantly below our levels from the last few years. For example, in 2022, we did not repurchase any shares under our authorized stock repurchase program.

The facilities described above are suitable for our present purposes, and the productive capacity in our facilities is being utilized or being prepared for utilization as we continue to make investments to expand our manufacturing capacity in support of our IDM 2.0 strategy.

Dataframe To Be made Like This:
[image: Dataframe To Be made Like This]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I.ve tried the multiple methods but its always outputs it wrong.